# High traffic php ajax chat design options

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

I have an High Traffic website, and I have implemented a webchat feature.
The problem is, I need to have 10k to 20k users online at the same time on the same page.  I have a 16gb Ram / 8 cores / ssd server, but when I reach about 7k concurrent users, the server goes down.

Now i'm using php/ajax/mysql chat, asking the server for new messages every 1 second - I know I shouldn't do this, so, what *can* I do?

It has been suggested to use the timestamp on a file and check the file instead of MySQL?  I'm not sure if that's a good solution.

Here is my Ajax code:

```
function verifychat() {
    //RUN THIS EVERY 1 SEC
    setTimeout(function () {
        // LAST MESSAGE ID
        var lastid = $(".chat-message-list .line:last-child").attr("data-row-id");

        // PAGE ID
        var channel = "<?php echo $channelname; ?>";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/ajax/channelchat.php",
            data: "verify&lastid="+lastid+"&channel="+channel,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {

                // IF PHP ANSWER IS "old"
                // THE ANSWER TELL IF HAVE NEW MESSAGES OR NOT
                if ($.trim(html) != "old") {

                    //APPEND TO BODY
                    $(".chat-message-list").append(html);
                    $(".chat-message-list .line:hidden").fadeIn()
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.chat-message-list').scrollTop($('.chat-message-list')[0].scrollHeight);
                    }, 100);
                };
            },
            complete: verifychat
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

This is the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_GET['verify'])) {
    //VERIFY IF HAS NEW MESSAGES // RETURN BOOLEAN
    $doit = $users->channel_chat_last_message($_GET["channel"], $_GET["lastid"]);

    //NO! NO! No comments about this "== false" ok? I like this way :)
    if ($doit == false) {
        echo "old";
    }else{
        foreach ($doit as $row){ ?>

        //GET THIS FOREACH USER INFO
        <?php $uinfo = $system->getLine("`id`, `rank`, `username`, `image_status`, `image_location`, `gender`", "users", "id", $row["user"]); ?>

        <div style="display:none;" class="line data-row-id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">      
            <div class="user">
                <?php echo $uinfo["username"]; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if ($general->logged_in() === true && $user["rank"] == 5){ ?>
            <div class="delete-message" data-row-id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="message">
                <?php echo $row["content"]; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        } 
    }
}
```

I am using PDO, and the called functions are MySQL queries.

Comment: Instead of having PHP (server) generate the divs etc... and JS appending. Why not just return key elements as JSON and have client side JS or jQuery parse JSON, and generate the new html + append?

Should reduce load + bandwidth a lot

Comment: I'm working on it right now :D https://i.gyazo.com/070a8bf15131a84b23d86a3d9de9086b.png

The thing is, should I use mysql query to check, or file timestamp check?

Comment: I am afraid I don't have the knoweldge to answer that question. But I notice from your script that you get a lot of fields  in $uinfo yet only use username. Is there a reason to get all this data :)? If so I would suggest not querying everytime since same user can have multiple chats. Have an array with userid as key. If user id not set then $system->getLine. Otherwise you already have it :)

Comment: yes, i deleted the other things becus the code for each message is giant, i have rank selector, message options, image checker and another things :)

Comment: I thing you have to use **websocket** over **ajax**

Comment: I tried, but I cant use it on my system, i think :/

Comment: if doing this with ajax only could use a cloud data service and make ajax requests there. Offloads a lot from your server. Also some services that have sockets

Comment: PHP + periodic polls is generally not the best technology choice for chats because of inefficient resource usage. Tools, that support event-oriented programming would do job better. For example you may implement your chat using long polls. In that case server side, that is responsible for holding long connections, could be implemented in nodejs. You don't need to rewrite all your PHP code, but you will need small separate nodejs process to manage long polls.

Comment: @amaksr do you have some example?

Comment: What about HTML5 websockets? would this work? like, when someone send  a message, socket call the message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions to improve performance.  Some of these have already been suggested, but I'll include them, so that you have a complete catalog.  Here they are, in no particular order:

1) Serve JSON from PHP, and render the HTML for the query in the client.  This should save you a considerable amount of processing time and bandwidth.

2) Minimize the number of fields that you query from MySQL, as each field has to be transferred and marshaled through PDO.

3) Consider using Comet to push messages to the Ajax clients over persistent connections.  You can read more about Comet at http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg28/index.html and http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

4) Consider caching your MySQL results in a [Memcached](https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached) or [Redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis).  This will consume some additional memory, but will dramatically decrease the overall overhead, and take an enormous load off of MySQL.  The biggest traffic sites in the world use these techniques to reduce overhead and significantly increase the number of concurrent users.

5) Find a way to use HTML5 websockets.  Webchat is one of the driving applications of HTML5 websocket, so this problem is ideally suited to the technology.

6) Consider reducing the refresh time from 1 second to between 2 and 5 seconds.  Users can't tell the difference between 1 and 2 seconds, and with a chat application, it takes considerably longer than 5 seconds to type most responses.  At 5 seconds, half of the messages will be delivered in less than 2.5 seconds, and the other half between 2.5 and 5 seconds, on average.  It's worth investigating, as a simple change to a 5 second polling interval would reduce your server overhead by 5X, which may be enough to support your current set of users with no code changes.